# Hot Questions suggestions showing question I am currently viewing

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Okay so I was viewing [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95747/my-contract-is-ending-is-it-acceptable-to-just-leave-without-any-talk-with-the) question when I noticed that the suggested *hot network questions* is still suggesting this page.. but I am currently viewing it already. [image]

I mean no offense to anyone, I have the utmost respect for the Stack exchange dev team and it isn't really a big deal and it harms no one I guess.. but maybe redesign *hot network questions* to show a different question instead?

It's just a little teeny tiny suggestion though.. and if it's like that by design then it's cool. Still love the site. Just trying to be helpful in the smallest way I guess